# LIRC in python: cannot see any code from infrared remote

Tags: python, lirc

I installed and configured Lirc on my Raspi, then I installed python-lirc. The Lirc configuration is OK, as I can use irw and irsend with no problem.

In my python program, when I try to read any IR code sent by my remote, the lirc.nextcode() function always return an empty list. The code is:

```
while (True):
    try:
            list = lirc.nextcode()
            if len(list) != 0: print "match!"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            lirc.deinit()
            break;
```

Also tried with pylirc library and have the same problem. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems unanswered elsewhere as well.
'lirc.nextcode() gives [] instead of key'

Your python script presumably has something like this before the lines you show?

```
sockid=lirc.init("myprogram")
```

Try adding the path of the .lircrc to the second init param:

```
sockid=lirc.init("myprogram","/home/pi/.lircrc")
```